# Exercise about branching process

Tags: probability-theory

Let $Z_n$ be a branching process with $Z_0=1$, $E(Z_1)=R<1$, $X_n:=\sum\nolimits_{k=0}^n Z_k$ and let $\psi_n(s)=E[s^{Y_n}]$ be the generating function. Define $X:=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{X_n}$ and $\psi(s)=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\psi_n}$.
Show that

a)  $\psi(s)=s\phi(\psi(s))$

b) $E[X]=\frac{1}{1-R}$

My approach was to show that
$\psi_{n+1}(s)=s\phi(\psi_n(s))$ and then take the limit on both sides for part a), but now i dont know how to solve part b)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach for a) is right.
For b) note that $EZ_n=R^{n}$. So $EX=\lim EX_n=\lim \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}R^{n}=\frac {1-R^{n+1}} {1-R} = \frac 1 {1-R}$. Interchange of limit and expectation is justified by Monotone Convergence Theorem.